# How do I append to a bash variable that is from a powershell output?

Tags: bash, powershell, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I am using WSL and need to get the computers IP address and append ":0.0". I execute a powershell command to get the IP address (random IP below) and assign that to a variable. Appending to that variable overwrites it.

```
> IP=$(powershell.exe "(Test-Connection -ComputerName (hostname) -Count 1).IPV4Address.IPAddressToString")
> echo $IP
127.27.15.1
> echo "${IP}:0.0"
:0.027.15.1
```

How do I get it to add it to the end instead of replacing the first 4 characters?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Remove the Windows line end from the value:

```
echo "${IP%$'\r'}:0.0"
```

Command substitution `$(...)` removes the final `\n`, but doesn't remove the `\r` that precedes it.

Parameter expansion `${var%pattern}` removes the pattern from the end of the var's value. `$'...'` enables the ANSI C escapes.